# How to increase percentage code coverage in jenkins pipelines for maven builds

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, devops

I am running a maven based pipeline in jenkins but getting sonar quality gates failure due to zero percentage code coverage. How can I increase the percentage code coverage through changes in pipeline script or in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube does not actually do the code coverage analysis. You have to run your unit tests with a probe (eg: jacoco) AND properly upload the [analysis results](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/).

Having that properly configured will get you above zero. Getting to 100% depends on proper and complete units tests.

SonarQube explains why the numbers might [not match expectations](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-and-code-coverage/4725)

Baeldung has a good explanation of configuring [Code Coverage with SonarQube and JaCoCo](https://www.baeldung.com/sonarqube-jacoco-code-coverage)

Comment: Actually this issue is occurring only with a feature branch. Main branch is perfectly fine with quality gates??

Comment: Nott preaemelty familiar w/paid for SQ variants, the ones that support multi-ranch analysis (since SQ 6.x). That should have been added.to your Q.

Comment: Actually I am running a single branch pipeline but not a multi-branch pipeline.