# multiple maven modules sonar code coverage is showing zero % on sonar qube

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using sonar version of 6.7.6 and maven 3.3.9 I'm having below configuration in my Jenkins its generating the jacoco reports and test cases reports as expected below paths.But I'm seeing 0% code coverage in sonarqube, can anyone please help me here?

```
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.junit.reportPaths=ABC-1/target/surefire-reports, ABC-2/target/surefire-reports, ABC-3/target/surefire-reports, ABC-4/target/surefire-reports, ABC-5/target/surefire-reports, ABC-6/target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=ABC-1/target/jacoco.exec, ABC-2/target/jacoco.exe, ABC-3/target/jacoco.exec, ABC-4/target/jacoco.exec, ABC-5/target/surefire-reports, ABC-6/target/jacoco.exec
sonar.projectKey=abc_Parent
sonar.projectName=abc_Parent
sonar.projectVersion=${POM_VERSION}
sonar.java.binaries=ABC-1/target/classes, ABC-2/target/classes, ABC-3/target/classes, ABC-4/target/classes, ABC-5/target/classes, ABC-6/target/classes
sonar.test.exclusions=**/src/test/**
sonar.sources=.
```

**MavenGoal**

-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -U clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:1.1.1:prepare-agent test

**ParentPOM**

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>***</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>***</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: If you found the answer all we your issue, consider marking as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, [SonarQube does not do the analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062421/598141), just imports the results.

*You really ought to [upgrade](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrade-notes/) to SQ LTS 8.9.x, which means going to [6.7.7](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-6.7.7.zip), then [7.9.6](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.6.zip), then to [8.9.x](https://www.sonarqube.org/success-download-community-edition/).*

Your coverage issues is that you must [`jacoco:prepare-agent`](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html), then run tests (`-DskipTests=false`), then produce a [`jacoco:report`](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html), or since you are multi-module, [`jacoco:report-aggregate`](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) and finally, `sonar:sonar`

The sonar-jacoco plugin can then pick the results up from the `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` location(s).

If "'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths" is not defined, default locations are:

> `"target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"`

SonarJava analyzer V 5.12. [deprecated use JaCoCo’s binary format (`.exec` files)](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151). Support for .exec format [JaCoCo Coverage Reports was dropped in SonarQube 8.2](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/lts-to-lts-upgrade-notes/#header-2)

According to the release notes for the [sonar-jacoco-plugin-1.1](https://jira.sonarsource.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=14683&styleName=&projectId=11734&Create=Create), it now has " Support wildcard in sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths "

SonarQube explains why the numbers [might not match expectations](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-and-code-coverage/4725)