# How to get SonarQube code coverage for scala project

Tags: scala, maven, sonarqube, jacoco, sonar-maven-plugin

I am running the goal from Teamcity for Scala project as
`org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent -U sonar:sonar`
My pom.xml file looks like:

```
<sonar-maven-plugin.version>2.0</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
<!-- Sonar -->
        <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.projectName>ds-rfds</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.projectDescription>ds-rfds</sonar.projectDescription>
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.scala.coverage.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/ds-rfds/target</sonar.scala.coverage.reportPaths>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.language>scala</sonar.language>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
```

I cannot get report and it giving error as:

```
Sensor Scoverage sensor for Scala coverage [sonarscala]
18:34:58
    [INFO] Importing coverage from /mrit_cm3/apps/teamcity/7.1.3/buildagent1/work/84f58bcce55c6907/ds-rfds/target
18:34:58
    [ERROR] File '/mrit_cm3/apps/teamcity/7.1.3/buildagent1/work/84f58bcce55c6907/ds-rfds/target' can't be read. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mrit_cm3/apps/teamcity/7.1.3/buildagent1/work/84f58bcce55c6907/ds-rfds/target (No such file or directory)
18:34:58
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mrit_cm3/apps/teamcity/7.1.3/buildagent1/work/84f58bcce55c6907/ds-rfds/target (No such file or directory)
```

How should I fix this?
I am using SonarQube Enterprise EditionVersion 7.9.1

Comment: You need to [jacoco:report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68157168/multiple-maven-modules-sonar-code-coverage-is-showing-zero-on-sonar-qube/68160007#68160007) or jacoco-report-aggregate

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube does not create code coverage report, it just reads it. I suspect that you missing command that will be crate report. It should look like this:

```
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.7</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
         <id>prepare-agent</id>
         <goals>
             <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
         </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
         <id>report</id>
         <phase>prepare-package</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>report</goal>
         </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
         <id>post-unit-test</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>report</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
             <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
             <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
             <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
             <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
     <systemPropertyVariables>
         <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
     </systemPropertyVariables>
 </configuration>
```

It is important to noticed this `<execution><id>post-unit-test</id>` part, since here is where file is created.

Also, you will need to set this path in sonarqube properties (path :`<SONAR_QUBE_INSTALL_FOLDER>\conf\sonar.properties`) and add the following:

```
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec
sonar.binaries=target/classes
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.verbose=true
```