# Code Coverage precentage is 0% in Sonarqube

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

I developed some JUnit tests using Jenkins pipeline for a Spring Boot App and and the Coverage percentage on SonarQube is still 0% (I believe this could be an issue from my script or my pom.xml)

Plugins installed On jenkins: Sonargraph + Sonarqube + Code Coverage API + Jacoco Plugin
This is the warning I get

```
[INFO] Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:report (report) @ achat ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Here is my Jenkins script stage for Sonar declaration:

```
sh '  mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.css.node=. 
-Dsonar.java.binaries=. -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.2.2:9000/ 
-Dsonar.login=admin   -Dsonar.password=sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/reports/jacoco.xml'
```

Here is my Test stage in jenkins:

```
sh '  mvn test'
jacoco execPattern: 'target/jacoco.exec'
```

Propreties in pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${basedir}/target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        
    </properties>
```

Plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                         <id>post-unit-test</id>
                          <phase>test</phase>
                           <goals>
                           <goal>report</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                      <outputDirectory>${jacoco.path}</outputDirectory>
                   </configuration>
                </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                            <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: The definition of jacoco-maven-plugin as dependency is simply wrong nor needed.

Comment: @khmarbaise hey , I just removed the dependency, I just update my full code in the question. Have a look at it again ,  I feel that I may be missing something.

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68160007/598141

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's clear that the jacoco and surefire plugins have to agree on where to find the data file, and what its name is. They do not, which is why this isn't working.

In addition, for recent plugin versions, you should probably use the xml format of the data file, not the binary version. In your current configuration, not only do they not agree on the location, one plugin is specifying the binary format, and the other the xml format.

I suggest you have property settings like the following:

```
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
<sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${basedir}/target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
```

In the Jacoco plugin, make sure you have this:

```
<execution>
    <id>post-unit-test</id>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${jacoco.path}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

The Surefire plugin needs this in the "configuration" block:

```
<argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
```

Comment: Hi sir,  I just did what you asked and someone below my question suggested my to remove the dependency, I just update my full code in the question. Have a look at it again ,  I feel that I may be missing something. I still face the same issue

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying here. I suggest you post a full update describing exactly what you have and what the result is.