# Getting 0% Sonar coverage, jacoco.xml not generated

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin

This is how my POM file looks like:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>3.1.5</spring-cloud.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.version>3.4.0.905</sonar.version>
        <swagger.version>3.0.0</swagger.version>
        <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    </properties>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar.version}</version>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

[image]

[image]

the coverage was coming 70% before, but it is coming as 0 after updating the versions of spring boot , sonar and jacoco. I have written the test cases. Sure fire reports are getting generated but I don't see jacoco.xml though jacoco.exec is generating

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple maven modules sonar code coverage is showing zero % on sonar qube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68157168/multiple-maven-modules-sonar-code-coverage-is-showing-zero-on-sonar-qube)

Comment: Your 0.0% are for NEW code only. What is the overall amount?

Comment: overall is also 0%

Comment: for all we know, you have zero tests written.

Comment: Actually , the coverage was coming 70% before, but it is coming as 0 after updating the versions of spring boot , sonar and jacoco. I have written the test cases. Sure fire reports rae getting generated but I don't see jacoco.xml though jacoco.exec is generating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Run `mvn clean install` (check if `jacoco.exec` is generated in the `target` folder).
2. Then run `mvn jacoco:report` (This will generate the `jacoco.xml` file which sonar will import and calculate the coverage)